# Converting null into ""

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax, null

How can I regex-replace null-values in String to become ""? Is there some way to allow a string to ignore null or turn it into ""?

```
    for (Row row : sheet) {

        cprCell = row.getCell(2);   //Kolonne med C

        String textValueForCPR = String.valueOf(cprCell);
        String convertNull = textValueForCPR.replaceAll((null), "");

        System.out.println(convertNull);

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean `textValueForCPR != null ? textValueForCPR : ""`?

Comment: `String.valueOf` never returns null. It may return `"null"`, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @AndyTurner    Apparently it does return null. It takes an empty excel cell and reads it as null

Comment: If you meant [NULL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) rather than null pointer (object reference), edit your Question to clarify.

Comment: ive tried to insert a codepoint U+0000 into every editor i have but cant get it to do it. if you do, what is the length if you add 5 U+0000 codepoints?

Comment: in generels i would assign string str = "";

Comment: Step one: Stop jumping to "regex" to solve every problem.

Comment: @Edward A string of 5 NULL characters has a length of 5. As seen running [live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CH1kGy): `"\u0000".repeat( 5 ).length()` ➙ 5

Comment: i cant seem to assign 5  '\0' to a string

Comment: how check that ? `if ( str == "\00\00\00\00\00" ) print("yes");` work, yes ? try it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for

```
String convertNull = textValueForCPR.replace("null", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

To delete any `NULL` characters with a Unicode code point of zero, call `String::replace` while passing single-character `CharSequence` using escape sequence `\u…` with hexadecimal number of zero (`\u0000`).

```
input.replace( "\u0000" , "" )
```

## Details

A `String` in Java cannot contain text *and* nulls, only either one. So I am guessing you use of the term `null` did did not mean a null object reference in Java.

## `NULL` character in Unicode & ASCII

You must mean to ask about deleting the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) 0 known as [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). (Also defined in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).) If my guess is correct, I suggest you edit your Question for clarity to avoid down-votes.

To do that, we need to represent a control character. The catch is that a control character by definition cannot appear in text. So we use the escape sequence in Java for identifying a character by hexadecimal number. The escape begins with a backslash and a `u`.

Note that we are doing a search-and-replace for a specific piece of text (a one-character [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html)). Therefore we should call [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) rather than `String::replaceAll` which takes a regex argument. While `replaceAll` technically works, using that method fails to represent our intention here and is inappropriate.

```
String input = … ;
String modified = input.replace( "\u0000" , "" ) ;
```

Example usage.

```
String input = "\u0000Dog\u0000Cat\u0000" ;
int lengthBefore = input.length();
String modified = input.replace( "\u0000" , "" ) ;
int lengthAfter = modified.length();

System.out.println( "lengthBefore = " + lengthBefore );
System.out.println( "lengthAfter = " + lengthAfter );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/aEskbt).

> lengthBefore = 9
>
> lengthAfter = 6

## Other avenues

### `String::trim`

The `String::trim` method removes leading and trailing [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) characters. Its definition of whitespace includes `NULL` character. Note that we are *not* removing the NULL in the middle of this example, only the NULL at the front and the NULL at the rear. So length is 7, 9-2.

```
"\u0000Dog\u0000Cat\u0000"
.trim()
.length()
```

> 7

If your string consists of nothing but a `NULL` character, the result is an empty string.

```
"\u0000"
.trim()
.length()
```

> 0

### Loop code points

You can loop each code point in your text. Get an `IntStream` (a stream of `int` primitives`) representing each character's code point. Test if the code point is zero (a` NULL` character).

```
"\u0000Dog\u0000Cat\u0000"
.codePoints()
.forEach( 
    ( int codePoint ) -> System.out.println( 0 == codePoint ) 
)
```

```
true
false
false
false
true
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: ( "\u0000" , "" ) ;   This doesnt seem possible to write after "replaceAll"

Comment: Please use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) when replacing a string instead of replacing a regex.

Comment: @PraiseDaMemes Yes it does work. See example [code running live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/aEskbt).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  Pls post ur answer as a proper Response so I can flag you. Your solution was the true answer, ty very much

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Good point. I changed my code and added a mention of your point about passing a `CharSequence` versus a regex as argument.